# Mock patching from/import statement in Python

Tags: python, python-mock

I am trying to get mock.patch to work on the following piece of sample code:

```
from mock import patch
from collections import defaultdict

with patch('collections.defaultdict'):
  d = defaultdict()
  print 'd:', d
```

This outputs the following:

```
d: defaultdict(None, {})
```

Which means that defaultdict was not patched.

If I replace the from/import statement with a straight import statement it works:

```
from mock import patch
import collections

with patch('collections.defaultdict'):
 d = collections.defaultdict()
 print 'd:', d
```

Output is:

```
d: <MagicMock name='defaultdict()' id='139953944084176'>
```

Is there any way to patch a call using from/import?

Thank you

Comment: See "Where to patch": https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you're patching something in the same module, you can use `__main__`:

```
from mock import patch
from collections import defaultdict

with patch('__main__.defaultdict'):
    d = defaultdict()
    print 'd:', d
```

If you're mocking something for an imported module, however, you'll want to use that module's name so the correct reference (or name) is patched:

```
# foo.py

from collections import defaultdict

def bar():
    return defaultdict()


# foo_test.py    

from mock import patch
from foo import bar

with patch('foo.defaultdict'):
    print bar()
```

The point here is that patch wants the full path to the thing it is patching.  This just looks a little weird when patching something in the current module, since folks don't often use `__main__` (or have to refer to the current module, for that matter).

Answer (score 16):

`patch` works by patching *names*.  You can't achieve anything by patching the name `collections.defaultdict` if you are using the name `defaultdict` (in the local namespace) to access the object.  See the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: Doesn't this mean that your unit tests will silently start behaving very, very differently if you change the implementation detail of whether you use `from X import Y` or `import X.Y`?

Comment: @detly: I believe that is true, although I'm not super familiar with mock so I can't say from experience.

Comment: Please see below.  I believe you are perhaps correct on the specific case and mistaken on the more general.  I have an example below based on something which works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The names can be very confusing in this case.  We always want to mock a class definition in a namespace.  The namespace is the module in which the import takes place.  The class definition is the name used in that namespace.

Let's take a concrete example:

- myproj.utilities module contains Actor class
- myproj.application imports this as `from myproj.utilities import Actor`
- my test should execute my.proj.application and mock our Actor

## myproj.utilities.py

```
class Actor:
    def __init__(name):
        self.name = name
```

## myproj.application.py

```
from myproj.utilities import Actor

class App:
    def __init__(name):
        self.actor = Actor(name)
```

## test code

```
from mock import patch
from myproj.application import App

test:
  # format: patch('<namespace>.<Class>')
  # the namespace in which we with to mock
  # the class definition we wish to mock
  with patch('myproj.application.Actor'):
      app = App('Someone')
      print( type(app.actor) ) # expect a MagicMock
```

I tried several other approaches and this one works well for me.  I have not tests the code above but instead generalized it from my own specific case.  So, it might be a little off.